# jquery onclick fires prematurely(?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I've got the following script - i have a menu, and when the user clicks 'about', the menu disappears, and some animated div appears, and when user clicks anywhere i want the animated div to go away, and menu to reappear.
the animation is restarted with x = setinterval(blabla), supposed to stop with document.click anywhere if x is not 0.

the problem is that it shows for a second and stops right after 'about' is clicked

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/EgtqF/

here:

```
 $('#about').click(function(){
        $('#menu div').fadeToggle(1000);
        $('#credits').fadeToggle(1000);
        refreshId = setInterval(function(){
            $('#credits').animate({'bottom':'100%'},5000,'linear',
                function(){
                    $('#credits').css({'bottom':'0%'})})},
            1000);
    });

    $(document).click(function(){
            if(refreshId != 0){
                clearInterval(refreshId);
                $('#credits').fadeToggle(100);
                $('#menu div').fadeToggle(100);
                refreshId = 0;
            }
        });
```

how do i get this to work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue an `event.stopPropagation()` from your `#about` click handler to ensure that the `click` event is not bubbled up to your `document` object.

```
$('#about').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   // ...
   return false;
});
```

Comment: `return false === e.stopPropagation() + e.preventDefault();`

Comment: excuse me, but i dont understand your solution

Comment: The problem looks like it is due to the click event being bubbled up to your document object. The solution above adds code to prevent this behavior. The `// ...` above refers to your current code. Btw, your fiddle isn't working (for me at least).

Comment: hmmm, weird i can run it np :|
yes i understand u now, now when i click my menu reappears, but the animation wont stop like the interval is not cleared. like the doc.click only runs part of code i put in there...
BTW if i run clearInterval(refreshId); in console it returns undefined, not tru\fal, weird, isnt it??